dataframe easily implement merge_asof
I have two dataframes:
time_start = datetime.datetime.strptime('2024-02-01 10:00:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
interval_l = [1, 7, 14, 17, 21, 22, 31]
df_l = pd.DataFrame(index = [time_start + datetime.timedelta(seconds=i) for i in interval_l])
df_r = pd.DataFrame(range(4), index = [time_start + datetime.timedelta(seconds=10*i) for i in range(4)], columns=['val'])
df_l.index.name = 'datetime'
df_r.index.name = 'datetime'


df_r is every 10 seconds with a val columns. I want to merge df_r to df_l with its closest forward time and keep the other times in df_l as nan.
Here is the expected result of df_l after merge:

I implemented a complicated method by using merge_asof two times and merge by the key of index:
df_l['time'] = df_l.index
df_r = pd.merge_asof(
    df_r,
    df_l[['time']],
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
    direction='forward',
    )
df_l = pd.merge_asof(
    df_l,
    df_r[['time', 'val']],
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
    direction='backward',
    by='time'
    )
df_l.drop(columns=['time'], inplace=True)

Is there any simple way to do this, such as directly using merge_asof?

Here's one approach:
r_idx = df_r.index[df_r.index <= df_l.index.max()]
mask = np.searchsorted(df_l.index, r_idx)
df_l.loc[df_l.index[mask], 'val'] = df_r.loc[r_idx, 'val'].values

Output:
                     val
datetime                
2024-02-01 10:00:01  0.0
2024-02-01 10:00:07  NaN
2024-02-01 10:00:14  1.0
2024-02-01 10:00:17  NaN
2024-02-01 10:00:21  2.0
2024-02-01 10:00:22  NaN
2024-02-01 10:00:31  3.0

Explanation / intermediates

Using boolean indexing, select from df_r.index where the values are smaller than or equal to df_l.index.max (stored as: r_idx). (This is irrelevant for your example, but if df_r.index were to have timestamps that are greater than df_l.index.max, not doing this would lead to an error below with applying mask.)
Use np.searchsorted to find the first suitable location to insert the values from r_idx, stored as mask.

mask

array([0, 2, 4, 6], dtype=int64) # index positions


Get the appropriate values from df_l.index via boolean indexing with mask and use inside df.loc to assign the underlying array of df_r.loc[r_idx, 'val'] (with Series.values).

df_l.index[mask]

DatetimeIndex(['2024-02-01 10:00:01', '2024-02-01 10:00:14',
               '2024-02-01 10:00:21', '2024-02-01 10:00:31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

Note that the above assumes that your indices are sorted and do not contain duplicate values.

That would also have been my first approach ;)

I probably would use a searchsorted approach as decribed by @ouroboros1, however you could achieve what you want with a single merge_asof. Just assign a unique value (e.g. the index) to df_r and the mask the duplicated indices:
out = (pd.merge_asof(df_l, df_r.assign(idx=df_r.index),
                     left_index=True, right_index=True)
         .pipe(lambda x: x.mask(x.pop('idx').duplicated()))
      )

Output:
                     val
datetime                
2024-02-01 10:00:01  0.0
2024-02-01 10:00:07  NaN
2024-02-01 10:00:14  1.0
2024-02-01 10:00:17  NaN
2024-02-01 10:00:21  2.0
2024-02-01 10:00:22  NaN
2024-02-01 10:00:31  3.0


Also nice for the OP to see a version that uses pd.merge_asof.
